# How is the JVM prevented from 'optimizing away everything' in this piece of example code from Effective Java?

Tags: java, optimization, jvm, effective-java

I found [this example code](https://github.com/jbloch/effective-java-3e-source-code/blob/master/src/effectivejava/chapter2/item6/Sum.java) for Joshua Bloch's book, Effective Java. It's meant to demonstrate why you should avoid unnecessarily creating objects:

```java
public class Sum {
    private static long sum() {
        Long sum = 0L;
        for (long i = 0; i <= Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++)
            sum += i;
        return sum;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numSets = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        long x = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < numSets; i++) {
            long start = System.nanoTime();
            x += sum();
            long end = System.nanoTime();
            System.out.println((end - start) / 1_000_000. + " ms.");
        }

        // Prevents VM from optimizing away everything.
        if (x == 42)
            System.out.println();
    }
}
```

What do the last two lines of the main method accomplish here?

Comment: Now, that I call a super quick comeback ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That final comparison is the only usage of that variable. Without it, who would care about the value in that variable?

Nobody!

So, the compiler might assume: that value is never used, and the code that writes to it has node side effects. Things that don't get used, why waste time writing to them.

Thus: that final first "read" usages prevents over eager compilerd from "optimizing out" the call to the method you intend to measure!

Answer (score 2):

The last two lines force the compiler to run the whole loop, to find the value of `x`. Otherwise it might detect that `x` is not being used at all and ignore the loop, given that inside of it no "real" work is being made. Even though `sum()` is called repeatedly, the result of accumulating its returned value would be discarded in the end if we do nothing with `x`.

Of course, this assumes that the `println()` statement inside the loop can be safely ignored, I'm unsure if the compiler can make such a decision. That would be one aggressive compiler!

Answer (score 0):

The two last lines will make sure that the JVM doesn't remove calls that it could potentially consider no-ops otherwise, one option is to use the result - so you might sum all the return values and then display the sum at the end.

Another way to prevent vm from optimizing is to disable JIT:

```
-Djava.compiler=NONE
```

JIT:

> When JVM compiles the class file, it doesn’t complete the full class
>   file; it compiles only a part of it on need basis. This avoids heavy
>   parsing of complete source code. This type of compilation is termed as
>   JIT or Just-In-Time compilation. JVM is Platform(OS) dependent Code
>   generation JIT is Platform Oriented, generates the native byte code,
>   so it is faster one than JVM :)